# Create a "repin" type action but with a unique description for each user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app it works similar to Pinterest where users upload an image (book cover) with a description and they can "like" another user's book which will add it to their profile. But, I want the description text to act as a recommendation so each user should write their own recommendation even if the book already exists on the site.

Is it possible to add a form on the book page so someone can write a new description when they "like" the book so the app creates a new book with all attributes simply copied over but with the new description? Will I need javascript for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**has_many :through**

You'll need to use a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) join model

[image]

This is what's known as a `many-to-many` relationship (meaning you can associate `many pins` to `many users` through `repins`). A HMT setup gives you the ability to add your own data to the join records - giving you the chance to create the descriptions you need for each repin:

```
#app/model/pin.rb
Class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :repins
   has_many :users, through :repins
end

#app/models/repin.rb
Class Repin < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | user_id | pin_id | description | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :pin
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :repins
   has_many :pins, through: :repins
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@pin = Pin.find params[:id]
@pin.repins.each do |repin|
   repin.description
end
```

or

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.repins.each do |repin|
   repin.description
end
```

Comment: How do I get description to be a field in Repin? Would it be `rails g migration AddDescriptionToRepins` ?

Comment: Yes, then you'll add a column like this: `add_column :repins, :description, :string`